# Select in select....?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to output a list of customers with the names and the count of events he has registered on.

Like this:

```
 max (3)Sports,Food,Cinema
 tom (2) Food, Sports
```

I Can't get it to work. I always get this result:

```
 max Sports
 max Food
 max Cinema
 tom Food
tom Sports
```

I have approximately this table Setup:

```
+-----+-----------+-------+-----+
+ CID + Customer  + misc..+ ... +
+-----+-----------+-------+-----+
+ 1   +   max      +  abc  + ... +
+-----+-----------+-------+-----+
+ 2   +  tom      +  xyz  + ... +
+-----+-----------+-------+-----+


+-----+------------+--------+---------+-----+
+ EID + RID        + Event  + misc... + ... +
+-----+------------+--------+---------+-----+ 
+ 1   +            + Sports + misc... + ... +
+-----+------------+--------+---------+-----+ 
+ 2   +            + food   + misc... + ... +
+-----+------------+--------+---------+-----+ 
+ 3   +            + cinema + misc... + ... +
+-----+------------+--------+---------+-----+ 
+ 4   +            + Event  + misc... + ... +
+-----+------------+--------+---------+-----+ 


+-----+-----+-----+
+ RID + EID + CID +
+-----+-----+-----+
+ 1   + 1   + 1   +
+-----+-----+-----+
+ 2   + 2   + 1   +
+-----+-----+-----+
+ 3   + 3   + 1   +
+-----+-----+-----+
+ 4   + 1   + 2   +
+-----+-----+-----+
+ 5   + 2   + 2   +
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I Have tried it with GROUP_CONCAT() but this seems not the way it wokrs....

I have JOINED all Tables but I think I need 2 querys to solve this task.

I tried a select in my while loop, but this is crap its extremly slow....

I Have tried this:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT  et.Art,  et.Kategorie, et.ID, et.Event AS Event1,
  GROUP_CONCAT( loc.ORT )       AS ORT1
  FROM ".DB_CUSTOMERS_TABLE."      AS et
  JOIN ".DB_RELATIONS_TABLE." AS rel
  ON (et.id =  rel.EID)
  JOIN ".DB_EVENT_TABLE."  AS loc
  ON (loc.Location_ID = rel.Location_ID)
  GROUP BY rel.EID
       ";
```

I need an idear, how i can solve this problem on an nice way.

thx for reading. I hope im not to confused.

Comment: Can you post what is the desired output and what you get
?

Comment: And did you check if you have all the columns other than the group_concat in group by clause? I mean you should have the group by as group  by et.Art,  et.Kategorie, et.ID, et.Event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve is an aggregated result per each Customer.

What you are currently doing is aggregating per Relationship, when it is the Relationship itself that is the subject of aggregation.

In order to do this, you must Group by the column you want the aggregation to apply to, ie: the Customer's name.

You can then use a simple COUNT() and GROUP_CONCAT to achieve the aggregation you desire.

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85daa/4

Comment: I think the overall answer is right. But should group by customer Id (CID) not by names. That 's what the Id is for. You could have more than one customer called 'Tom' in you table :-)

Comment: What if i would like to count actual events (maybe 2) and separately past events ( maybe 4)   ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to group on every field you're selecting other than the one you want to list out, it's hard to tell because your query doesn't match the info given in your question, but simplified from your example would be:

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Event)
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

So it may be as simple as:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT  et.Art,  et.Kategorie, et.ID, et.Event AS Event1,
  GROUP_CONCAT( loc.ORT )       AS ORT1
  FROM ".DB_CUSTOMERS_TABLE."      AS et
  JOIN ".DB_RELATIONS_TABLE." AS rel
  ON (et.id =  rel.EID)
  JOIN ".DB_EVENT_TABLE."  AS loc
  ON (loc.Location_ID = rel.Location_ID)
  GROUP BY et.Art,  et.Kategorie, et.ID, et.Event 
       ";
```

But can't be certain that's what you're actually after given the info in your question.

If you have a query that returns:

```
 Name Event
 max  Sports
 max  Food
 max  Cinema
 tom  Food
 tom  Sports
```

You could just wrap it in the simple group concat example above:

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Event)
FROM (Your query) as sub
GROUP BY Name
```